# jq: Add values of a specific key for all objects with same ID

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON array that contains a lot of objects and it looks like this:

```
[
{"ID":"A","VALUE":12,"TYPE":"single"},
{"ID":"A","VALUE":17,"TYPE":"single"},
{"ID":"A","VALUE":-7,"TYPE":"single"},

{"ID":"B","VALUE":35,"TYPE":"single"},
{"ID":"B","VALUE":10,"TYPE":"single"},
{"ID":"B","VALUE":15,"TYPE":"single"},

{"ID":"C","VALUE":0,"TYPE":"single"},
{"ID":"C","VALUE":13,"TYPE":"single"},
{"ID":"C","VALUE":20.5,"TYPE":"single"}
]
```

Now I would like to add all values for every ID and create new objects with the results like this:

```
{"ID":"A","VALUE":22,"TYPE":"total"},
{"ID":"B","VALUE":60,"TYPE":"total"},
{"ID":"C","VALUE":23.5,"TYPE":"total"}
```

Additionally, the resulting objects should be added to the initial array.

I am pretty new to jq so I did some research. Indeed I know how to get the totals for an ID:

```
[.[] | select(."ID"=="A").VALUE]|add

-> 22
```

and how to create new objects:

```
.[] | {ID: .ID, VALUE: .VALUE, TYPE: "total"}
```

But how do I get the format I want from here? With a loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution which uses [reduce](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce) to compute the totals, generate objects in the specified format and add them to the original input array:

```
 . + [
     reduce .[] as $r ({}; .[$r["ID"]] += $r["VALUE"])
   | keys[] as $id
   | {ID:$id, VALUE:.[$id], TYPE:"total"}
 ]
```

Note that the value this computes with the sample data for C is `33.5` which I believe is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can group them up by the `ID`, then aggregate them into the new objects.  Then combine that with the existing array of items.

```
[.[], (group_by(.ID)[] | { ID: .[0].ID, VALUE: map(.VALUE)|add, TYPE: "total" })]
```